# Add brackets for latitude and longitude

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a CSV file which has longitudes and the latitudes in it:

input.csv

```
103.771 1.44849,103.771 1.44894,103.771 1.4489,103.772 1.44802,103.772 1.4479,103.774 1.44948,103.775 1.4501,103.778 1.4512,103.78 1.45145,103.781 1.45151,103.783 1.45118,103.786 1.45035,103.787 1.45007,103.789 1.4492,103.79 1.44898,103.791 1.44918,103.793 1.4498,103.793 1.44984,103.794 1.44939,103.795 1.44816,103.797 1.44214,103.798 1.44095,103.797 1.44036,103.796 1.43938,103.793 1.4383,103.793 1.43779,103.791 1.43624,103.79 1.43503,103.789 1.43341,103.788 1.43235,103.788 1.43208,103.788 1.43161,103.787 1.4299,103.787 1.42869,103.788 1.42771,103.789 1.42693,103.79 1.42592,103.79 1.42401,103.79 1.42279,103.79 1.42149,103.789 1.41974,103.789 1.41716,103.788 1.4146,103.788 1.41244,103.787 1.41201,103.786 1.41175,103.785 1.41141,103.784 1.41095,103.783 1.41079,103.782 1.41072,103.78 1.41074,103.78 1.41074,103.778 1.41071,103.776 1.41079,103.775 1.41056,103.773 1.41008,103.772 1.4101,103.771 1.42498,103.772 1.43239,103.772 1.43484,103.772 1.43566,103.771 1.44849
```

I want to add brackets and a comma between each coordinate set which will result like

output.csv

```
[103.771,1.44849],[103.771,1.44894],[103.771,1.4489],[103.772,1.44802],[103.772,1.4479],[103.774,1.44948],[103.775,1.4501],[103.778,1.4512],[103.78,1.45145],[103.781,1.45151],[103.783,1.45118],[103.786,1.45035],[103.787,1.45007],[103.789,1.4492],[103.79,1.44898],[103.791,1.44918],[103.793,1.4498],[103.793,1.44984],[103.794,1.44939],[103.795,1.44816],[103.797,1.44214],[103.798,1.44095],[103.797,1.44036],[103.796,1.43938],[103.793,1.4383],[103.793,1.43779],[103.791,1.43624],[103.79,1.43503],[103.789,1.43341],[103.788,1.43235],[103.788,1.43208],[103.788,1.43161],[103.787,1.4299],[103.787,1.42869],[103.788,1.42771],[103.789,1.42693],[103.79,1.42592],[103.79,1.42401],[103.79,1.42279],[103.79,1.42149],[103.789,1.41974],[103.789,1.41716],[103.788,1.4146],[103.788,1.41244],[103.787,1.41201],[103.786,1.41175],[103.785,1.41141],[103.784,1.41095],[103.783,1.41079],[103.782,1.41072],[103.78,1.41074],[103.78,1.41074],[103.778,1.41071],[103.776,1.41079],[103.775,1.41056],[103.773,1.41008],[103.772,1.4101],[103.771,1.42498],[103.772,1.43239],[103.772,1.43484],[103.772,1.43566],[103.771,1.44849]
```

How can I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed "s#,#],[#g;s# #,#g;s#^#[#;s,$,]," input > output
```

awk solution

```
awk -F, '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
     sub(" ",",",$i);
     i==NF?out=O $i C:out=O $i C",";
     printf("%s",out)
}
}'  O="[" C="]" input > output
```

---

```
awk '{gsub(",","],["); sub(/^/,"["); sub(/$/,"]"); sub(" ",",")}1' input > output
```

Comment: if we use other delimiters, we don't need to backslash the [ ]

Comment: just noticed that, we don't need to escape. Then its pretty much same. ( except useless use of cat )

Answer (score 0):

I might try:

```
 cat infile | sed 's/,/\],\[/g
 s/ /,/g
 s/^/\[/
 s/$/\]/' > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question `awk`, one way of doing it (without looping over fields explicitly) would be

```
awk -F, -vOFS='],[' '
  {$0 = "[" $0 "]"; $1=$1; gsub(" ",","); print}
' input.csv
```

However IMHO it would be simpler and more natural to simply match and capture space-separated pairs of strings and re-substitute them in `sed`

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*) ([^,]*)/\[\1,\2\]/g' input.csv
```